# Is there any way to extract column from CSV file based on user input using shell scripting?

Tags: bash

If I want 2nd column is there a way to script that will take my input and show that respective column.

Comment: This depends on how reliable the solution needs to be. (i.e. working with CSV files with quoted delimiters).

Comment: Welcome to So, it is always recommended to post sample of Input and expected output along with your efforts in your post too @Sree

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data.csv is a CSV file...

```
cat data.csv | cut -f2 -d','
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to take input from user and print any column which is entered by user then following may help you.

```
cat script.ksh
echo "Please enter field number which you want to get:"
read value

awk -v val="$value" '{print $val}' Input_file
```

Comment: @Sree, kindly do update in post how suggestions went did they help or not, so that all who tried to help you could be aware of it please/.

Answer (score 0):

Below ask for input and based on the entered value, will print the columns.

`echo "enter value"
read number
awk -F "," -v num=$number '{print $num}' data.csv`